# HTML5 Section - how to markup and style on this scenario?

Tags: css, html

I've been give this layout where I have a section, with some information. 
However, visually, that section has some rows across 100% wide the screen, while the content is only 70%.

Styles are inline for clarification proposes:

**Question 1** - is this an acceptable markup ?

```
<section>
  <div class="row-red" style="width=100%; background-color: red;">
    <h1 style="width:70%">section header here</h1>
    <p style="width:70%">paragraph 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row-blue" style="width: 100%; background-color: blue;">
    <p style="width:70%">paragraph 2</p> 
  </div>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance

here's an example taking from the fiddle wrote here on the first place:

http://jsfiddle.net/gSLww/9/

Comment: Do you have an example of how this actually looks? a jsfiddle perhaps?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: He never said they need to stack horizontally.

Comment: This is quite a subjective question, but in terms of purely semantic markup, I think you've chosen a perfectly acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a acceptable Markup but only you have to work on it CSS. Write like this:

```
.row-red,.row-blue{
    padding-right:30%
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
  <div class="row-red" style="background-color: red;">
    <h1>section header here</h1>
    <p>paragraph 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row-blue" style="background-color: blue;">
    <p>paragraph 2</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/gSLww/15/